# Get script to create database including initializer data

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I wonder if there's a possibility with Entity Framework's Migrations to get the sql script to create the content of my database including all the data from my seed method in the Configuration class:

```
protected override void Seed(Sotasa.DAL.SqlContext context)
{
    //Data I'd like to be included to the script
}
```

Help of the Update-Database command doesn't look like it could be done:

```
Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName 
<String>] [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: You already found the `Seed` method, so could you please specify what isn't clear yet?

Comment: The seed method seeds database content to a new/existing database.
I'd like the generated script to contain this contain.

Comment: ?? Please show some code (however immature) of what you'd like to do in the seed method. You've got a context there so you can do any CRUD action you like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script EF migration seed from Configuration class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417939/script-ef-migration-seed-from-configuration-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. (To have data generated in Seed method generating SQL statements).

An alternative workaround is to use a script to build -> create database -> script the database with data? (Powershell probably can do it tapping into sql server management objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done, might not be so pretty but it works for us (note this is for our local dev and CI environments):

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator(OracleConnectionInfo.InvariantName, new OracleEntityMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        Logger.Write("In Seed method. User: " + userName);
        MyInitializer.AddUpdateDataSql(context);
    }
}

public class MyInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>
{
    private const string Schemaname = "MYSCHEMA";

    public static void AddUpdateDataSql(Pronova2Context context)
    {
        DeleteTableData(context);
        DropCreateSequences(context);
        PopulateTypeTypeData(context);
        // etc.
    }

    private static void DeleteTableData(DbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE1"); }
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete " + Schemaname + ". T_TABLE2"); }
        // etc.
    }

    private static void DropCreateSequences(DbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"DROP SEQUENCE  " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE1_SEQ"); }
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"DROP SEQUENCE  " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE2_SEQ"); }
        // etc.
    }

    private static void PopulateTypeTypeData(DbContext context)
    {
        try { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Insert into " + Schemaname + ".T_TYPE_TYPE (TYPE_TYPE_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (1,'TypeType1','Name 1')");
        try { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Insert into " + Schemaname + ".T_TYPE_TYPE (TYPE_TYPE_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (2,'TypeType1','Name 2')");
        // etc.
    }
}
```