# Generate SQL script to Seed initial data with Entity Framework v6.1 Code First

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

When deploying an application that makes use of Entity Framework v6.1 Code First I use `Update-Database -Script` to obtain a SQL statement I can execute against my database. How can I generate a similar script that will `Seed` my database with the initial data? My Production server does not have Visual Studio installed nor do I want it installed there. I would like to be able to hand the DBA a script for creating the schema (which I have as mentioned above) and one for seeding the initial data.

Comment: Define "Seed my database with initial data". If you are referring to lookup tables, then you should have that scripted with `Insert` and `Values`. Unless I'm totally missing something here.

Comment: I should be more specific. I have code in my `Seed()` method in my `Configuration.cs` file. I was looking for a way to have this code execute and take the data changes made in the database and create a SQL script. This code adds roles to the tables but uses the Identity framework to do so, thereby resulting in guids for identity columns.

Comment: You can't script via migrations. You could script via SSMS as described [here at bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417939/script-ef-migration-seed-from-configuration-class) I seed identity using the [Initializer Seed](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) in code. This is different than migration seed and only runs when the database is created. Another option might be using [migrate.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618307(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a database that is already seeded, there is an export capability (data only) in SSMS that allows you to create a script of seed data.  There is a good article here. (https://keyholesoftware.com/2016/12/12/creating-a-sql-database-project-for-isolated-development/)

The premise is to use a pre-seeded database as a model.  This is a re-hash of the keyholesoftware information in the link above along with a couple of comments I find personally useful.

- Select the initial seeded database and right click | Tasks |
  Generate Scripts
- Select Tables from objects
- Use a single
  file for each table (provides more control)
- Choose a directory
  (sandbox) where you keep your seed data (you should create a folder
  in your visual studio project for this location. (If you want the
  files kept in a virgin state, choose a sandbox for your location and
  then move them to this folder you create when you finish this part
  of the export.)
- In the advanced section (advanced button) change
  the "types of data scrpt" to data only
- Script "Use Database" to
  false (you're still in the advanced section do this to export to your files) and finish with this part, close the advanced portion, and close the wizard.

Hand these off to your DBA - on the other hand, assuming you have Visual Studio:

- Back in VS, (I'm using VS2017), show all files (it is an icon in the solution explorer off
  to the right)
- Include your exported tables (from the sandbox you
  created just now).  You'll need to either set the properties of each
  from "build" to "none" (its the first choice in the property), or go
  close your project and edit the csproj file for the project to
  change the way it handles the included files.  I use alt-Enter to
  open each property and set the build to none. (If it happens to you, the ERROR you'll see is "SQL71006)
- If you have
  the postdeploy folder in your project, right click that now (or
  create it now and copy your files to this folder from your "sandbox").
- Right click
  the postdeploy folder and add script | "post deployment script"
- open the script in VS. select the "sqlcmd" mode.  Caveat here - make
  sure your network allows sqlcmd to run - some restrict its
  capability - check with your sysadmin if you aren't sure what your
  production environment holds in store for restrictions.
- add commands for the tables you wish to use the seed data.  You may need
  to use SSMS to script a drop and create on your tables so that you
  can get around the constraints that may prevent you from running
  your table scripts.  I started with the users - I immediately had to
  drop the constraints from that table in order to import.   I added
  them drop constraints before running the post-deployment script and
  then re-create the constraints at the end of the script.
- Clean and Rebuild your database project
- Publish your project - it
  should create your database and add the seed data (open publish -
  connect to the database you are publishing to - save the profile -
  use the default location - click publish.
- The process should be
  able to repeat itself.  The first few times I deleted and recreated
  the database, but re-publishing over the current seems to work just
  fine.

NOTE - if you get an SQL71006 error, see jamie thompson's answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47d4124b-82cd-48f9-8ba7-c2ae4c73cbcf/sql71006-why-am-i-getting-this-error?forum=ssdt&prof=required